# In $a = dv/dt$, is $a$ the net acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, differentiation, calculus

While going through the calculus approach to accelerate, we have,

$$a = dv/dt, $$
I think, here, v and a should be in the same axis,

is my process correct?

in a planar motion in two dimensions, it will become,

a net = dv net/ dt, but I think it will not work,

pl clarify this confusion,
thanks.

Comment: What does the $\hat{net}$ operator mean?

Answer (score 4):

In two dimensions, the velocity of a particle is a vector-valued function of time:
$$\vec v(t)=v_x(t)\mathbf{\hat x}+v_y(t)\mathbf{\hat y}.$$
Whenever you have a particle whose motion is in the plane, its acceleration is defined to be:
$$\vec a(t)={d\vec v(t)\over dt}.$$
So if you know the velocity, you can always find the acceleration via the above definition. This is the time derivative of a vector-valued function, so there are components of the velocity in the $x$ and $y$ direction, i.e.
$$\vec a(t)={d\vec v(t)\over dt}={d v_x(t)\over dt}\mathbf{\hat x}+{d v_y(t)\over dt}\mathbf{\hat y},$$
the magnitude of which can be calculated:
$$|\vec a(t)|=\sqrt{\bigg({d v_x(t)\over dt}\bigg)^2+\bigg({d v_y(t)\over dt}\bigg)^2}.$$
Below in the comments, on JG notes that one must be careful when working in a non-cartesian basis. This is so important that I will elaborate a bit.

For example, if you have motion in a circle at constant velocity, one does not have to switch to a non-cartesian basis, e.g. I can write the motion with respect to cartesian components:
$$\vec v(t)=-\omega\sin(\omega t)\mathbf{\hat x}+\omega\cos(\omega t)\mathbf{\hat y}.$$
One can calculate the acceleration using the given definition:
$$\vec a=-\omega^2\cos(\omega t)\mathbf{\hat x}-\omega^2\sin(\omega t)\mathbf{\hat y}.$$ No problems, since the $\mathbf{\hat x}$ and $\mathbf{\hat y}$ basis vector do not depend on time. On the other hand, if I had chosen to represent the velocity of the particle in the polar basis, i.e.$\mathbf{\hat r}$ and $\mathbf{\hat\theta}$, then one cannot simply differentiate the coordinates as in the example above as the polar basis vectors are not constant in time. For exmaple,
$${d\over dt}f(r, \theta)\mathbf{\hat\theta}=f^\prime (r, \theta)\mathbf{\hat \theta}+f(r,\theta){d\mathbf{\hat\theta}\over dt}. $$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152087/discussion-on-answer-by-albertus-magnus-in-a-dv-dt-is-a-the-net-accelerat); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.